# Переменная в теле функции и доступ к ней из другой

Tags: javascript

Дело в том, что объявляя переменную в теле two() я не могу получить доступ к ней в функции one(). alert() срабатывает только один раз, дальше ошибка, "myConst is not defined".

Если же определить ее вне функции, то все работает, но специфика моего стрипта такова, что ее нужно опеделять именно внутри...

```html
<input value="Click me!" type="button" id="myButton">

<script>

function one() {
    alert(myConst);
}

function two() {
    const myConst = 'myConst';
    document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(myConst);
        one();
    });
}

two();

</script>
```

Как исправить?

UPD:

```
function loadForm() {
   
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function() {
        
        const elementResult = document.querySelector('#form-container');

        elementResult.innerHTML = this.responseText;

        const elementForm = document.querySelector('[name="contact-form"]');
        const elementName = elementForm.querySelector('[name="name"]');
        const elementEmail = elementForm.querySelector('[name="email"]');
        const elementMessage = elementForm.querySelector('[name="message"]');
        const elementKey = elementForm.querySelector('[name="key"]');
        const requestURL = elementForm.action;
        
        elementForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            sendForm();
        });

    }

    xhttp.open("GET", "mailer/?action=form", true);
    xhttp.send();

}

function sendForm() {

   const name = encodeURIComponent(elementName.value);
   const email = encodeURIComponent(elementEmail.value);
   const message = encodeURIComponent(elementMessage.value);
   const key = encodeURIComponent(elementKey.value);

   /* Здесь формируется и отправляется запрос */
}
```

Comment: "но специфика моего стрипта такова, что ее нужно опеделять именно внутри..."  --- почему?

Comment: Содержимое формы подгружается средствами AJAX. И только потом, когда она заргузилась, имеет место быть ссылка к каждому из элементов формы через метод querySelector()...

Answer (score 1):

Делаем так

```
function one(myConst) {
    alert(myConst);
}
```

и так

```
one(myConst);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, но это не совсем то...

Comment: ........Почему?

Answer (score 0):

в js до ужаса простой и приятный ООП, попробуйте его.

```js
var x ={
a: 0,
b: function(){this.a = 123;},
c: function(){this.b(); alert(x.a);},
d: function(id){return document.getElementById(id)},
e: function(css) {return document.querySelector(css)}
}
var y = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
```

```html
<input id='def' value='987'/>
<input type='button' value='x.c' onclick='x.c();'/>
<input type='button' value='x.d' onclick='alert(x.d("def").value);'/>
<input type='button' value='y' onclick='alert(y("def").value);'/>
```

если менять парадигму посреди проекта лень(редактировать 1+мб кода я б тоже не стал ради единичного случая), можно попробовать писать не в переменные а скажем в печеньки или localstorage. можно просто создать внешний json-объект\массив и все писать в него.

а вообще, если то что после "UPD" и есть ваш код, эммм... создавать эти "переменные" нет никакого смысла, при наличии прокси геттера(в примере выше методы `x.d();`, `x.e();` и переменная `var y` как раз и есть примеры прокси геттеров).